# CSS transition on newly created element

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, css

I have a page where I want to dynamically change the background color of an element which is subsequently recreated by an ajax call.  Because of this, any class or inline CSS I add is replaced a second or so later.

Since newly created element begins it's life with the background-color style already defined, it has nothing to transition *from*, hence the lack of a transition. So far, I haven't been able to find a viable workaround.  **For the sake of this question, please assume that I do not have control over the timing and/or content of the element created by the ajax call.**

```js
$('#change-by-class').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('green');
});
$('#change-by-dom').on('click', function() {
  $('#new-style').html('#change-by-dom { background-color: lightgreen; }');

  // THIS PART IS SIMLULATING AN AJAX EVENT WHICH I DO NOT HAVE CONTROL OVER - ASSUME YOU CANNOT CHANGE IT
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#change-by-dom').remove();
    $('<div id="change-by-dom">Click to Change Color by DOM</div>').appendTo('#container');
  }, 300);
});
```

```css
#container > div {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  -ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.green {
  background-color: lightgreen
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style id="new-style"></style>
<div id="container">
  <div id="change-by-class">Click to Change Color by Class</div>
  <div id="change-by-dom">Click to Change Color by DOM</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```js
$('#change-by-class').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('green');
});
$('#change-by-dom').on('click', function() {
  $('#new-style').html('#change-by-dom { animation: bkg 1s linear forwards; }');
  $('#change-by-dom').remove();
  $('<div id="change-by-dom">Click to Change Color by DOM</div>').appendTo('#container');
});
```

```css
#container > div {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.green {
  transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  background-color: lightgreen
}

@keyframes bkg {
  100% {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style id="new-style"></style>
<div id="container">
  <div id="change-by-class">Click to Change Color by Class</div>
  <div id="change-by-dom">Click to Change Color by DOM</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works to some extent, but assuming the ajax call is not **instant**, it results in a double animation.  If you wrap the creation of the new element in a `setTimeout` to simulate the ajax delay you'll see what I mean: `  setTimeout(function() { 
  $('#change-by-dom').remove();
  $('<div id="change-by-dom">Click to Change Color by DOM</div>').appendTo('#container');
     }, 1000);`

Comment: @billynoah If you add a style to an element it applies ... and this is an animation, so it animates. After a delay you delete it, add a new and then that one animates. How else should it work?

Comment: @billynoah So don't add the style until you want it to animate.

Comment: I understand.  I want the animation to begin immediately but not get interrupted when the element gets rewritten.. perhaps this is impossible and your answer might be the closest thing.  Considering listening for an ajax complete event to begin animation is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: For completeness sake, here's a jfiddle with simulated scenario: https://jsfiddle.net/4zr889b7/

Comment: @billynoah If you want to wait until done before rewrite it, you'll need to listen to the animation event.

Comment: It's somewhat of the opposite.  I think I need to listen to the ajax event and just wait until it's done it's thing.  I don't think there is a way to have an animation that continues smoothly while the object is being recreated.  Since your answer is probably the closest thing to what I need and it taught me something cool, I'm accepting it.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('#change-by-class').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('green');
});

$('#change-by-dom').on('click', function() {
  $('#new-style').html('#change-by-dom { background-color: lightgreen; }');
  $('#change-by-dom').remove();
  var $elem = $('<div id="change-by-dom">Click to Change Color by DOM</div>').appendTo('#container');
  $elem.css({ 'background-color': 'white', 'transition': 'none' }).width();
  $elem.css({ 'background-color': '', 'transition': '' })
});
```

```css
#container > div {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  -ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.green {
  background-color: lightgreen
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style id="new-style"></style>
<div id="container">
  <div id="change-by-class">Click to Change Color by Class</div>
  <div id="change-by-dom">Click to Change Color by DOM</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you.  That would be someone else.  That being said, you aren't quite understanding.  I've revised my question to be a bit more clear about what's what.